# how do I move my checkbox in front of my nav bar in html / css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a check box to check on and off the nav bar, but it floats behind my nav bar, so I can't actually see it. I've tried to play with margins and spacing, but can't seem to get it to work. Eventually, I want to change the nav and header background color to white, but have been playing around with black just to try to get it to appear. If there is also an ability to change the color of the checkbox, that would be incredible too.

Code:

```css
/* general formatting starts here */

:root {
  --gd2-blue: rgb(13, 192, 255);
  --gd2-gray: #a1a1a1;
  --header-color: black;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* navigation styles start here */

#gd2-ventures-logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}

header {
  background: var(--header-color);
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -67px;
  height: 97px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--header-color);
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

nav a {
  color: var(--gd2-gray);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.nav-toggle:checked~nav {
  display: block;
}


/* content styles start here */

.content {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: var(--gd2-blue);
  font-family: "Aldhabi", serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 150px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <h1 class="logo">
    <img id="gd2-ventures-logo" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/RQ5b6Z9JKq5shKOTrkpM8mdlX3c0N270wCSMB-sCjuyumIXLMsbjQGUS14jmLE31ZJ8EGuFjrg4VAAolUIAnKjqTb6Z2yguvvtemLnNhEF0TGdo42Dtsj5lcsclEXS9GYIbdUWFFADo=w2400" alt="GD2 Ventures Logo">
  </h1>

  <input type="checkbox" class="nav-toggle">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<div class="content">
  <h2>GD<sup>2</sup> Ventures</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the error to be honest.

```css
/* general formatting starts here */

:root {
  --gd2-blue: rgb(13, 192, 255);
  --gd2-gray: #a1a1a1;
  --header-color: white;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* navigation styles start here */

#gd2-ventures-logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}

header {
  background: var(--header-color);
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--header-color);
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

nav a {
  color: var(--gd2-gray);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav{
  display: block;
}
/* content styles start here */

.content {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: var(--gd2-blue);
  font-family: "Aldhabi", serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 150px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header>

    <img id="gd2-ventures-logo" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/RQ5b6Z9JKq5shKOTrkpM8mdlX3c0N270wCSMB-sCjuyumIXLMsbjQGUS14jmLE31ZJ8EGuFjrg4VAAolUIAnKjqTb6Z2yguvvtemLnNhEF0TGdo42Dtsj5lcsclEXS9GYIbdUWFFADo=w2400" alt="GD2 Ventures Logo">
  
  <input type="checkbox" class="nav-toggle">
  
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<div class="content">
  <h2>GD<sup>2</sup> Ventures</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* general formatting starts here */

:root {
  --gd2-blue: rgb(13, 192, 255);
  --gd2-gray: #a1a1a1;
  --header-color: black;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* navigation styles start here */

#gd2-ventures-logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}

header {
  background: var(--header-color);
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -40px;
}

nav {
  text-align: left;
  background: var(--header-color);
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

nav a {
  color: var(--gd2-gray);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

/* content styles start here */

.content {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: var(--gd2-blue);
  font-family: "Aldhabi", serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 150px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.nav-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("nav-toggle");
  var text = document.getElementById("nav");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    nav.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     nav.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
<header>

  <h1 class="logo">
    <img id="gd2-ventures-logo" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/RQ5b6Z9JKq5shKOTrkpM8mdlX3c0N270wCSMB-sCjuyumIXLMsbjQGUS14jmLE31ZJ8EGuFjrg4VAAolUIAnKjqTb6Z2yguvvtemLnNhEF0TGdo42Dtsj5lcsclEXS9GYIbdUWFFADo=w2400" alt="GD2 Ventures Logo">
  <div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle" onclick="myFunction()">
  </div>
 </h1>
 
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<div class="content">
  <h2>GD<sup>2</sup> Ventures</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This kind of works, but with an end goal of having a nav bar that can be responsive, I need to have the checkbox fixed to directly under the logo. How would we do that?

Comment: @Kevin I made some changings. Now the checkbox is fixed directly under the logo.

Comment: Thank you! It is so close to what I need, but now the nav is not flush with the checkbox. Is there a quick fix to getting them on the same level?

Comment: I think it has something to do with my photo. I am following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QKOaTYvYUA. And have basically copied the code line for line, except for inputting and playing around with my own logo and color schematic

Comment: @Kevin I actually don't understand what you want. 
Do you want the nav items centered?

Comment: I am trying to recreate the work that they did in the video. The goal is to create a responsive navigation bar that can be tab-able, fixed to the top, creating the dropdown without any JS, using a flexbox and css grid to lay it out. 

That is the goal and I was partly through the exercise, but have run into this hiccup where I can't get the checkbox to function in conjuction with the nav bar

Comment: https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/jxppmr You can watch his codepen, you can find your solution here.

Comment: Thanks. That was an older version that doesn't have the mobile features and drop downs built in. The newer version takes both of these into account. I posted on his discord, so if no one here knows what to do, I will be sure to post the solution when I find it.